# Python/MySQL mathmatic

Tags: python, mysql

So I have a MySQL database to which I connect and I have two rows in the specific table, one of them is VARCHAR and the other is INT.

This is how I enter the database using Python:

```
player = seluse.get()
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
cursor = cnx.cursor()
sql = "SELECT * FROM db_PROMOTIONS WHERE player = '%s'" % (player)
cursor.execute(sql)
results = cursor.fetchall()
for row in results:
    prank = row[1]
```

Now there is no problem at the moment, but I want to decrese the "prank" variable which in MySQL is a INT.
I do that by:

```
prank = prank - 7
```

Now this pops up a problem for me:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1536, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Python27/Scripts/data.py", line 201, in insert_new
    prank = prank - 7
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'unicode' and 'int'
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should convert prank to `int`:

```
for row in results:
    prank = int(row[1])
```

when you get a value using mysql.execute, all returning fields are string.
You can use `SQLAlchemy` instead to convert value automatically,